# Bash Process Execution Logic

Tags: python, bash, scripting

I have a number of scripts to run, some of which have one or more scripts that must be completed first. I've read a number of examples showing how bash's control operators work, but haven't found any good examples to address the complexity of the logic i'm trying to implement.

I have p_01.py and p_03.py that are both requirements for p_09.py, but also have individual processes that only require p_01. For example:

```
((python p_01.py & python p_03.py) && python p_09.py) & 
(python p_01.py && 
    (
        (python p_05.py;
         python p_10.py) &
        (python p_08.py;
         python p_11.py)
    )
)
wait $(jobs -p)
```

My question is, how can I accomplish all of the scripts running only after their requirements without repeating the running scripts (such as p_01.py, which you'll notice it's used twice above)? I'm looking for a generalized answer with some detail, since in actuality the dependencies are more numerous/nested than the example above. Thank you!

Comment: How about a solution in python instead of bash?

Comment: I avoided Python because my goal is parallelism and also needed to avoid circular imports.

Comment: Python doesn't preclude either of those.

Comment: @chepner - what approach would you suggest? Subprocess? concurrent futures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are thinking of the scripts in terms of their dependencies, that's difficult to translate directly to a master script. Consider using `make`, which would let you express these dependencies directly:

```
SCRIPTS = $(wildcard *.py)

.PHONY: all
all: $(SCRIPTS)

$(SCRIPTS):
    python $@

p_05.py p_08.py p_09.py: p_01.py
p_09.py: p_03.py
p_10.py: p_05.py
p_11.py: p_08.py
```

Running `make -B -j4` would run all of the Python scripts with up to 4 executing in parallel at any one time.

Comment: I was thinking of a similar solution in python but `make` is purpose-built for this kind of thing and the dependencies are clearly specified.

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look at the docs and test it out when I'm at a computer. Quick add-on question: how do I specify an order to run the scripts in? Is it just the order of the lines' requirements?

Comment: You don't. `make` will figure out the order based on the dependencies.

Comment: The order in which you *run* them doesn't matter, only the order in which you *start* them.

Comment: Thanks - I think for my purposes I'm going to end up researching more/writing in python afterall, but this was very helpful/informative and certainly answered the question I posted here.